# Fetching end-user Computer name and displaying it on website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement , I need to display the client computer name(computer name/User name) when some access my website, Is it possible?

If a user with computer name  "Miely" visits my site, i have to display "Welcome Miely", so this is my requirement, and is there anyway to do tis via PHP? Im interested to know solution from any JS libraries.
Please help , thank you.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan : That is giving me any result, nothing is alerted, im checking in chrome on winxp, can you please assist?

Comment: It will not work on any other browser except IE, as it uses activX object. ActivX objects are only for IE

Comment: See here for example for what IS possible: http://www.mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp?bhjs=0